# Electronic Data Interchange Processing in Java

Tags: java, api, e-commerce, erp, edi

My requirement is to process the EDI (Electronic data interchange) file and create the appropriate records in my application , then send back the acknowledgement back in EDI format.

I want to know any standard API available for creating and processing EDI documents in Java.

Also give me some references (Books) to understand the EDI Standard formats for E-commerce and ERP.

Thanks, 
Vel.

Comment: And I got a few hits when I Googled for "java edi api".

Comment: ...or you (or your client) can purchase (or rent as SaaS) a commercial translator that does all the heavy lifting for you.  Why these people want to reinvent this 30+ year old wheel all the time is baffling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand EDI and develop parsing and persisting for EDI you must fist know about their grammar (Loops, segments and fields). below are EDI Loops for your understanding purpose.

LOOP 1000A PAYER IDENTIFICATION

LOOP 1000B PAYEE IDENTIFICATION

LOOP 2100 CLAIM PAYMENT INFORMATION

As for i know there is no Java API, you must implement their selves. In order to understand their grammar and development guidelines you must purchase their guide (Not open source).

"Health Care Claim Payment/Advice" for ePayment 835

"Health Care Claim: Professional" for eClaim 837

Comment: *"As for i know there is no Java API"* - not in Java SE.  But if you Google, you will find a few likely candidates.